# How to run python query directly from teamcity

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have 2 machines on which I need to download Anaconda.sh and some compiled zipped files. One machine is Linux where I downloaded all zip files plus .sh files using below curl command:

```
curl -s -o cmake-3.4.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz  http://ccm-XYZ/tools/cmake-3.4.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

As this is the linux machine, I am calling it from teamcity and it's working fine as expected. Unfortunately, I'm getting issue with the Windows machine.

I want the same behaviour for windows. I want to download .gz file as mentioned above from the teamcity build step and then extract it. As of now, I am using python script as below:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("curl -s -o cmake-3.4.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz  http://tools/cmake-3.4.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz", shell=True)
```

It is not running. Any suggestions here. How can I get into python interactive mode to run the python scripts?

Comment: Downvoting because of trolling with some sentences like "getting issue with the Windows machine, as usually we get error on windows."

Comment: Any error stack trace?

Comment: No.. It's not giving any error or warning while running from teamcity.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an order from python with:

```
import os
os.system('--- your command ---')
```

Anyway, I do not know if your order is going to work...

Another way could be with:

```
import commands
commands.getoutput('--- your command ---')
```

Comment: Already did.. In this case, Python is unable to organize 'curl'. Getting error "'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command...."

Comment: Can't use it, it's a third-party module. Validation is to use only in-built modules for the execution of the task.